# Where does the foreach ($filterItems as $filterItem) coming in Magento 2 layered navigation (filter.phtml)

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

I am customising **`public_html\vendor\magento\module-layered-navigation\view\frontend\templates\layer\filter.phtml`** in custom module.I need to find which method or controller the `foreach ($filterItems as $filterItem):` is coming so I can call that method or block in my custom file.

```
 <ol class="items">
<?php foreach ($filterItems as $filterItem): ?>
    <li class="item">
        <?php if ($filterItem->getCount() > 0): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($filterItem->getUrl()) ?>">
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $filterItem->getLabel() ?>
                <?php if ($this->helper('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data')->shouldDisplayProductCountOnLayer()): ?>
                    <span class="count"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $filterItem->getCount()?><span class="filter-count-label">
                        <?php if ($filterItem->getCount() == 1):?> <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('item')?><?php else:?> <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('items') ?><?php endif;?></span></span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this class **`Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer`** and inside this class a public method **`render(FilterInterface $filter)`** is responsible for initializing `$filterItems` in `filter.phtml`

This line is responsible **`$this->assign('filterItems', $filter->getItems())`**  for initializing  `$filterItems`.

Answer (score 1):

Attributes data is assigned from multiple files.

For Price type attributes please refer to the below file:

- vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php

For Dropdown, Multiple type attributes please refer to the below file:

- vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php

For Category attributes please refer to the below file:

- vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php

You can customize the _getItemsData method for all the above files.

Answer (score 0):

It is cominng from as argument from 
`vendor\magento\module-layered-navigation\view\frontend\templates\layer\view.phtml` file.

```
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getChildBlock('renderer')->render($filter) ?>
```

`getFilters()` function of `Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation` class is responsible for loading all the applicable Filters.